# Non contiguous ranges into monodimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

i have an array declared as follow:

```
MyArr = Sheets("xls").Range("A1:A" & last_row).Value2
```

i'd like to add another Range .Range("D1:D" & last_row).Value2 to it, how would i do it?

or... any easy way to create an array from non contiguous ranges? i need a monodimensional array without blanks as result from the follow ranges

```
Range("A1:A100") and Range("AL1:AM:120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ary() As Variant, i As Long
    Dim r As Range
    i = 1
    For Each r In Union(Range("A1:A100"), Range("AL1:AM120"))
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve ary(1 To i)
            ary(i) = r.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```